# Configuring Webpack to Execute TypeScript + Mocha Tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, mocha.js

I'd like to configure webpack to transpile (mocha + chai) tests written in typescript to javascript and them execute them. To that end, I have the *webpack.test.config.js* file below. Note: I've currently configured webpack to use *ts-loader* and *mocha-loader*.

Unfortunately, when I execute `webpack --config webpack.test.config.js --env.dev`, I receive the error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:10) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.

How can resolve this error and achieve my aforementioned goal?

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const outputPath = './bin/test';

module.exports = env => {
  return {
    mode: env && env.pro ? 'production' : 'development',
    context: path.resolve('src'),
    entry: {
      core: './test/typescript/core.spec.ts'
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: path.join(__dirname, outputPath)
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin({
        dry: true,
        cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['./bin/test/**/*']
      })
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.spec\.tsx?$/,
          use: ['mocha-loader', 'ts-loader'],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    }
  };
};
```